# Pandas: Cell frequency count by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is a long list of 4 letters, `'A', 'T', 'G','C'`, I need to count the frequency of each letter by index

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cases': ['ACCTTGTAGTGTATTTTATGACCAAATGACTTTTTCCCCCCAGTGGCTAATTTGTCTCAGGCCTGCGTCTTAAAGAGACACGGTAATGAGTAGGAAGTCCAGCGTGGTCTGGA','ACCTTGTACTGTATCTTATGACCAGATGACTTTTTCCACCCAGTGGCTAATTTGTCTCAGGCCTCCGTCTTAAAGAGACACGGTAATGAGTAGGAAGTCCAACGTGGTCTAGA','GCCTTGTACTGTATATTATGACCAAATGACTTTTTCCACCCATTGGCTAATTTGTCTCAGGCCTCCGTCTTAAAGAGACACGGAAATGAGTAGGAAGTCCAGCGTGGTCTAGA','ACCTTGTACTGTATATTATGACCAGATGACTTTTTCCACCCAGTGGCTAATTTGTCTCAGGCCTCCGTCTTAAAGAGACACGGTAATGAGTAGGAAGTCCAGCGTGGTCTAGA']})
```

```
                                               cases
0  ACCTTGTAGTGTATTTTATGACCAAATGACTTTTTCCCCCCAGTGG...
1  ACCTTGTACTGTATCTTATGACCAGATGACTTTTTCCACCCAGTGG...
2  GCCTTGTACTGTATATTATGACCAAATGACTTTTTCCACCCATTGG...
3  ACCTTGTACTGTATATTATGACCAGATGACTTTTTCCACCCAGTGG...
4  ACCTTGTACTGTATATTATGACCAGATGACTTTTTCCACCCAGTGG...
5  ACCTTGTAGTGTATTTTATGACCAAATGACTTTTTCCCCCCAGTGG...
6  ACCTTGTACTGTATCTTATGACCAGATGACTTTTTCCACCCAGTGG...
7  GCCTTGTACTGTATATTATGACCAAATGACTTTTTCCACCCATTGG...
8  ACCTTGTACTGTATATTATGACCAGATGACTTTTTCCACCCAGTGG...
9  ACCTTGTACTGTATATTATGACCAGATGACTTTTTCCACCCAGTGG...
```

The result would be a new df of shape `4x113`, i cannot figure out a pandas way to do this. Below is my non-pandas solution

```
def freq_lists(dna_list):
    n = len(dna_list[0])
    A = [0]*n
    T = [0]*n
    G = [0]*n
    C = [0]*n
    for dna in dna_list:
        for index, base in enumerate(dna):
            if base == 'A':
                        A[index] += 1
            elif base == 'C':
                C[index] += 1
            elif base == 'G':
                        G[index] += 1
            elif base == 'T':
                T[index] += 1
    return {'A': A, 'C': C, 'G': G, 'T': T}

fdf = pd.DataFrame(freq_lists(df['cases'].to_list()))
```

```
     A  C  G  T
0    3  0  1  0
1    0  4  0  0
2    0  4  0  0
3    0  0  0  4
4    0  0  0  4
..  .. .. .. ..
108  0  4  0  0
109  0  0  0  4
110  3  0  1  0
111  0  0  4  0
112  4  0  0  0
```

To clarify the first row is obtained by summing up the counts of the first str in the `case` column which is `AAGA -> A: 3, C:0, G:1 T:0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use collections.Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
df['cases'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(Counter(x)))
```

output:

```
    A   C   T   G
0  27  24  34  28
1  29  26  33  25
2  30  25  33  25
3  29  25  33  26
```

The other way around it not as sexy:

```
pd.DataFrame([Counter(i)
              for i in list(zip(*df['cases'].apply(list).values))]
            ).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

or

```
(df['cases'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))
            .apply(pd.value_counts)
            .T.fillna(0).astype(int)
)
```

output:

```
     A  G  C  T
0    3  1  0  0
1    0  0  4  0
2    0  0  4  0
...
111  0  4  0  0
112  4  0  0  0
```

Comment: @ScottBoston I can't get it to work, it counts on the wrong axis. Also isn't `df['cases'].str.split('').str[1:-1]` better replaced by `df['cases'].apply(list)`?

Answer (score 5):

Let us do `explode` with `crosstab`

```
s = df.cases.map(list).explode()
out = pd.crosstab(s.groupby(level=0).cumcount(),s)
Out[583]: 
cases  A  C  G  T
row_0            
0      3  0  1  0
1      0  4  0  0
2      0  4  0  0
3      0  0  0  4
4      0  0  0  4
   .. .. .. ..
108    0  4  0  0
109    0  0  0  4
110    3  0  1  0
111    0  0  4  0
112    4  0  0  0
```

Comment: @Kenan The dataframe you provided to copy/paste only has 4 sequences

Comment: I just realized that sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 4):

Let us try [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), then [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on `level=1` followed by [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) to reshape

```
l = df['cases'].str.extractall('(\w)')
l[0].groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

---

```
       A  C  G  T
match            
0      3  0  1  0
1      0  4  0  0
2      0  4  0  0
3      0  0  0  4
4      0  0  0  4
5      0  0  4  0
6      0  0  0  4
7      4  0  0  0
8      0  3  1  0
9      0  0  0  4
10     0  0  4  0
...
...
110    3  0  1  0
111    0  0  4  0
112    4  0  0  0
```

Comment: I think that number of As is not correct in the first row if you compare it to the desired output in the question.

Comment: @Hamzawi Its correct when you run the code given by OP on the provided dataframe it will generate the exact same output.

Comment: @Hamzawi this matches the questions method and input data. The output in the question is incorrect for the input they have supplied.

Comment: sorry about the confusion, I didn't realized I only copied the first few rows

Answer (score 2):

Try with `pd.get_dummies`:

```
>>> df['cases'].apply(lambda x: pd.get_dummies(list(x))).sum()
     A  C  G  T
0    3  0  1  0
1    0  4  0  0
2    0  4  0  0
3    0  0  0  4
4    0  0  0  4
..  .. .. .. ..
108  0  4  0  0
109  0  0  0  4
110  3  0  1  0
111  0  0  4  0
112  4  0  0  0

[113 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest `.str.split('', expand=True)` as a way to separate the letters into columns, then we could simply aggregate using `value_counts`:

```
>>> df['cases'].str.split('', expand=True)
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
0     A  C  C  T  T  G  T  A  G  T  G  T  A  T  T  T  T  A  T  G  A  C  C  A  A  A  T  G  A  C  T  T  T  T  T  C  C  C  C  C  C  A  G  T  G  G   
1     A  C  C  T  T  G  T  A  C  T  G  T  A  T  C  T  T  A  T  G  A  C  C  A  G  A  T  G  A  C  T  T  T  T  T  C  C  A  C  C  C  A  G  T  G  G   
2     G  C  C  T  T  G  T  A  C  T  G  T  A  T  A  T  T  A  T  G  A  C  C  A  A  A  T  G  A  C  T  T  T  T  T  C  C  A  C  C  C  A  T  T  G  G   
3     A  C  C  T  T  G  T  A  C  T  G  T  A  T  A  T  T  A  T  G  A  C  C  A  G  A  T  G  A  C  T  T  T  T  T  C  C  A  C  C  C  A  G  T  G  G   
4     A  C  C  T  T  G  T  A  C  T  G  T  A  T  A  T  T  A  T  G  A  C  C  A  G  A  T  G  A  C  T  T  T  T  T  C  C  A  C  C  C  A  G  T  G  G   
5     A  C  C  T  T  G  T  A  G  T  G  T  A  T  T  T  T  A  T  G  A  C  C  A  A  A  T  G  A  C  T  T  T  T  T  C  C  C  C  C  C  A  G  T  G  G   
6     A  C  C  T  T  G  T  A  C  T  G  T  A  T  C  T  T  A  T  G  A  C  C  A  G  A  T  G  A  C  T  T  T  T  T  C  C  A  C  C  C  A  G  T  G  G   
7     G  C  C  T  T  G  T  A  C  T  G  T  A  T  A  T  T  A  T  G  A  C  C  A  A  A  T  G  A  C  T  T  T  T  T  C  C  A  C  C  C  A  T  T  G  G   
8     A  C  C  T  T  G  T  A  C  T  G  T  A  T  A  T  T  A  T  G  A  C  C  A  G  A  T  G  A  C  T  T  T  T  T  C  C  A  C  C  C  A  G  T  G  G   
9     A  C  C  T  T  G  T  A  C  T  G  T  A  T  A  T  T  A  T  G  A  C  C  A  G  A  T  G  A  C  T  T  T  T  T  C  C  A  C  C  C  A  G  T  G  G   
>>> counts = df['cases'].str.split('', expand=True).agg(pd.Series.value_counts)
>>> counts
     0    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8    9     10    11    12    13    14   15    16    17    18    19    20    21  ...    26    27    28    29    30    31    32    33    34    35    36    37   38    39    40    41    42   43    44    45    46    47
   10.0  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0
A   NaN  8.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0   NaN  6.0   NaN   NaN  10.0   NaN   NaN  10.0  ...  10.0   NaN   NaN  10.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  8.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
C   NaN  NaN  10.0  10.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  8.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  2.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0  10.0  2.0  10.0  10.0  10.0   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
G   NaN  2.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0   NaN   NaN  2.0   NaN  10.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN  10.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  8.0   NaN  10.0  10.0   NaN
T   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0  10.0   NaN  10.0   NaN  NaN  10.0   NaN  10.0   NaN  10.0  2.0  10.0  10.0   NaN  10.0   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN  10.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0  10.0  10.0  10.0  10.0   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  2.0  10.0   NaN   NaN   NaN

[5 rows x 48 columns]
```

With some little cleanup, including a `.shift(-1, axis='columns')` to move from 1-indexing to 0-indexing:

```
>>> counts.fillna(0, downcast='infer').shift(-1, axis='columns').iloc[1:, :-2]
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45
A   8   0   0   0   0   0   0  10   0   0   0   0  10   0   6   0   0  10   0   0  10   0   0  10   4  10   0   0  10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0  10   0   0   0   0
C   0  10  10   0   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0  10  10   0   0   0   0   0   0  10   0   0   0   0   0  10  10   2  10  10  10   0   0   0   0   0
G   2   0   0   0   0  10   0   0   2   0  10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  10   0   0   0   0   6   0   0  10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   0  10  10
T   0   0   0  10  10   0  10   0   0  10   0  10   0  10   2  10  10   0  10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  10   0   0   0  10  10  10  10  10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2  10   0   0
```

Alternately `.str.split()` can also be used with `explode()`, in which case @BENY’s `cumcount` grouping can be reused with `value_counts()`:

```
>>> letters = df['cases'].str.split('').explode()
>>> counts = letters.groupby(letters.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).value_counts()
>>> counts.unstack('cases', fill_value=0).drop(columns='').shift(-1, fill_value=0).iloc[:-2].head(10)
cases   A   C   G   T
0       8   0   2   0
1       0  10   0   0
2       0  10   0   0
3       0   0   0  10
4       0   0   0  10
5       0   0  10   0
6       0   0   0  10
7      10   0   0   0
8       0   8   2   0
9       0   0   0  10
```

Or even closer to @BENY’s answer, using `cumcount()` and `pd.crosstab` after `.str.split('').explode()`:

```
>>> letters = df['cases'].str.split('').explode()
>>> counts = pd.crosstab(letters.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), letters)
>>> counts.drop(columns='').shift(-1, fill_value=0).iloc[:-2].head(10)
cases   A   C   G   T
row_0                
0       8   0   2   0
1       0  10   0   0
2       0  10   0   0
3       0   0   0  10
4       0   0   0  10
5       0   0  10   0
6       0   0   0  10
7      10   0   0   0
8       0   8   2   0
9       0   0   0  10
```

Here’s a quick performance comparison on my system with different sizes:

[image: performance comparison of various answers on my machine]

So the fastest for all sizes is @BENY’s with `.str.split('')` instead of `.map(list)`, which is also the last presented in this post.

Below the code to generate these benchmarks

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, timeit, collections

rows = 100_000
reps = 1_000_000 // rows
glob = {'cases': pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list('ABCD'), (113, rows))).agg(''.join).rename('cases'), 'pd': pd, 'Counter': collections.Counter}

print('list + crosstab:', timeit.timeit('s = cases.map(list).explode() ; pd.crosstab(s.groupby(level=0).cumcount(),s)', globals=glob, number=reps) / reps)
print('split-explode + crosstab:', timeit.timeit('s = cases.str.split('').str[1:-1].explode() ; pd.crosstab(s.groupby(level=0).cumcount(),s)', globals=glob, number=reps) / reps)
print('extractall:', timeit.timeit("cases.str.extractall(r'(\w)')[0].groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)", globals=glob, number=reps) / reps)
print('split-expand + value_counts:', timeit.timeit("cases.str.split('', expand=True).agg(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0, downcast='infer').shift(-1, axis='columns').iloc[1:, :-2].T", globals=glob, number=reps) / reps)
print('split-explode + value_counts:', timeit.timeit("s = cases.str.split('').explode() ; s.groupby(s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).value_counts().unstack('cases', fill_value=0).drop(columns='').shift(-1, fill_value=0).iloc[:-2]", globals=glob, number=reps) / reps)
print('dummies sum:', timeit.timeit("cases.apply(lambda x: pd.get_dummies(list(x))).sum()", globals=glob, number=reps // 10) / (reps / 10))
print('Counter:', timeit.timeit("cases.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(Counter(x)))", globals=glob, number=reps // 10) / (reps / 10))
```

Comment: I got different results on my machine, when running them separably on jupyter notebook with %%timer, dummies+sum:19.3s, counter:115ms, extractall:2.05s, split-explode+crosstab:3.73s, split-explode+groupby:653ms

Comment: @Kenan 115ms for counter? That’s very surprising, anyting with `.apply()` is bound to be slow (as you can see on my plot too)

Comment: @Kenan You ran all those with 2000 though? For 1000 I had none beyond .3s (except dummies+sum) so I find 19s and the like very surprising again.

Comment: I wonder if the difference in our approach is because of how jupyter notebook does ``%%timer` vs `timeit`. The run time differences are very noticeable

Comment: That’s possible @Kenan, maybe `%%timer` takes into account the time it has to wait for a worker on the server of something. You can run `timeit` inside a jupyter notebook though.